# SimpleMembershipProvider WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection failing with an empty sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.5

I just added a sqlserver connection string. fresh new database. I checked the connection is 
fine on server explorer.

```
<add name ="club" connectionString="Data Source=server1;Initial Catalog=temp;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Then referenced it in **InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute** as follows

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("club", "Users", "UserID", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

It works in a sdf file and creates the tables. But fails with sql server. Anyone seen this error before and can explain what is happening?

Error -

Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.

Comment: Are you sure the database server is Sql Server?  Which version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add  `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` to your connection string.

```
<add name="club" 
  connectionString="Data Source=server1;Initial Catalog=temp;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```